# Filling object with pattern in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, patterns

I've figured out how to fill a rectangle object with a bitmap pattern:

- File->Import. To import the pattern file
- Then, select the pattern and do Objects->Pattern->Objects To Pattern
- And finally, selecting the rectangle object, go to the "Fill and Stroke" panel and choose the new pattern

The problem is, it doesn't work as expected... Instead of perfectly connecting, there is this 1 pixel transparent line around each "tile" of the filled object. This is an example of what I'm seeing. On the right, the pattern image, and on the left, the filled rectangle:

[image: Object with a bitmap pattern]

Any idea how to solve this? Would you say it's a bug?

I'm using the Mac OSX Snow Leopard Build --- v 0.48.2 r9819

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug and it's already fixed. Unfortunately we don't seem to have up to date nightly builds for Mac anymore, so you'll have to wait for 0.48.3 :-( I don't feel justified to ask you to build inkscape from source code :-/

Comment: Thanks. I might check how hard would it be to build it. Do you know which was the revision it got fixed on [inkscape's SVN](http://inkscape.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/inkscape/inkscape_web/?view=log)?

Comment: Apparently, it was 10326