# Inkscape: bitmap pattern filling - 1px line around every tile

Tags: inkscape, patterns, fill

I want to fill an object with a bitmap pattern.
Instead of perfectly connecting, there is this 1 pixel transparent line around each "tile" of the filled object.

The same problem was described here: [Filling object with pattern in inkscape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5006/filling-object-with-pattern-in-inkscape)

In reference to this post, the bug was fixed in 0.48.3, but I'm using 0.48.4 r9939 and the problem still exists.

See:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEXt7.png]

The used pattern: http://subtlepatterns.com/bo-play/

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filling object with pattern in inkscape](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5006/filling-object-with-pattern-in-inkscape)

Answer (score 1):

This bug is still in the latest stable releases of Inkscape 0.48.x. The bug that was reported as fixed in 0.48.3 was in relation to SVG based patterns. The bug you are hitting is for bitmap patterns (https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/167900)

It has, however been fixed in trunk/master, and will be available when the next version of inkscape is released (oddly it will have the version number 0.91)

If you want to try out a development version of inkscape to see if the fix works for you, you may be able to find a link to a build for your platform here -- http://inkscape.org/en/download/